# How to better implement base class property extencibility mechanism with OOP design patterns

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, extensibility

In my project I have hierarchy of classes which implements custom properties. Here is more close to what I want version for the console application.

```
class Property
{
    string key;
    object value;

    public Property(string key, object value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(key=" + key + ": value=" + value + ")";
    }
}

public struct PropertyConfig
{
    public string key;
    public object defaultValue;
}

abstract class BaseClass
{
    Dictionary<string, Property> properties = new Dictionary<string, Property>();

    Dictionary<string, PropertyConfig> mergedConfigs = new Dictionary<string, PropertyConfig>();

    public BaseClass()
    {
        MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances(
            new PropertyConfig[]
            {
                new PropertyConfig() { key = "p1",  defaultValue = "v1" },
                new PropertyConfig() { key = "p2",  defaultValue = "v2" }
            }, 
            true);
    }

    protected void MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances(PropertyConfig[] configs = null, bool IsBaseClass = false)
    {
        configs = configs ?? new PropertyConfig[] { };

        foreach (PropertyConfig config in configs)
        {
            mergedConfigs[config.key] = config;
        }

        if (!IsBaseClass)
        {
            CreatePropertyInstancesAfterMerge();
        }
    }

    private void CreatePropertyInstancesAfterMerge()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PropertyConfig> kvp in mergedConfigs)
        {
            PropertyConfig config = kvp.Value;

            properties.Add(config.key, new Property(config.key, config.defaultValue));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType().Name + ".Properties: " + string.Join(",", properties.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
    }
}

class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClassA(): base()
    {
        MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances();
    }
}

class DerivedClassB : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClassB() : base()
    {
        MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances(new PropertyConfig[]
        {
            new PropertyConfig() { key = "p2",  defaultValue = true },
            new PropertyConfig() { key = "p3",  defaultValue = "v3" }
        });
    }
}

class DerivedClassC : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClassC() : base()
    {
        MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances(new PropertyConfig[]
        {
            new PropertyConfig() { key = "p2",  defaultValue = false },
            new PropertyConfig() { key = "p4",  defaultValue = "v4" }
        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClassA derivedA = new DerivedClassA();
        DerivedClassB derivedB = new DerivedClassB();
        DerivedClassC derivedC = new DerivedClassC();

        Console.WriteLine(derivedA.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(derivedB.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(derivedC.ToString());


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Base abstract class defines a configuration of its property objects which are intended to be inherited in derived classes.

In the constructor configuration array is passed to `MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances` method call with second parameter set to `true` indicating that the instantiation of property objects have to be postponed.

Current state of the merged property configuration is stored in the `mergedConfigs` `Dictionary`.

Derived classes pass local property configuration to merge/override with base class configuration calling `MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances` method in its constructor with second parameter set to its default value `false` indicating that now property instances have to be created after merge.

The resulting output is below.

```
DerivedClassA.Properties: (key=p1: value=v1),(key=p2: value=v2)
DerivedClassB.Properties: (key=p1: value=v1),(key=p2: value=True),(key=p3: value=v3)
DerivedClassC.Properties: (key=p1: value=v1),(key=p2: value=False),(key=p4: value=v4)
```

And it is what I needed, but there are some disadvantages of this solution which I do not like:

1) It is necessary to call `MergeWithInheritedConfigsAndCreateInstances` in each constructor. Second parameter have to be provided in the abstract class constructor.

I'd like to have a solution where all the merge/instantiate mechanism was implemented and invoked in the base class. And to be able to define derived class specific property configuration not as a method parameter but rather as member field/property (maybe of static?).

2) The merging process is done each time class is instantiated.

I'd prefer to have it done only once. (placing in static constructor?)

UPD: Rewritten example code which is better demonstrates the intended idea.

Comment: fyi: this is how XAML/WPF works under the hood with dependency properties...

Comment: In my code I cannot rely on the wpf structures. And although requirements seem similar the internal implementation of the wpf dependency property system is highly specific to its domain and implementation details can not be reused here as is.

Comment: It was not about reusing their concrete classes, but rather the idea behind it ... :/

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over-complicating things. Even for a complicated setup, this should suffice:

```
class BaseClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    protected string this[string key]
    {
        get { string value; return properties.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : null; }
        set { if (value == null) properties.Remove(key); else properties[key] = value; }
    }

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this["p1"] = "v1";
        this["p2"] = "v2";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType().Name + ".Properties: " + string.Join(",", properties.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}:{kvp.Value}"));
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
        this["p2"] = "update";
        this["p3"] = "v3";
    }
}
```

But frankly, this is simpler and more obvious:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string P1 {get;set;}
    public string P2 { get; set; }
    public BaseClass()
    {
        P1 = "v1";
        P2 = "v2";
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType().Name + ".Properties: " + string.Join(",", GetType().GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(p => $"{p.Name}:{p.GetValue(this)}"));
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string P3 { get; set; }
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
        P2 = "update";
        P3 = "v3";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, Of course I oversimplified the code. Task is to implement sort of  dependency property system. Each property class has its logic. Base class implements pub/sub, getters/setters for different types of property values. Cross references. Properties can be added/removed on the fly. 
With this question I need to find solution for one part of the property system which provides initialization of properties defined in base class and to allow to inherit/override/merge them with the set of properties defined in derived class. 
If it is oversimplified too much ask and I will reformulate it.